# PHP Chat - SetInterval alternatives

Tags: php

I need to build a chat in PHP, all is clear and fine until the Chat box update.

For the Chat box update (so that chat updates automatically) for what I was investigating it is only possible by using the function JS SetInterval on the client side.

But isn't this a security flaw? For example if I set the SetInterval to 10 seconds but someone on the client side changes this JS to 1 milliseconds and every millisecond there will be a request to the server. (I assume this hack is possible, is it not?)

What is the most secure way you advise to make a PHP chat page updating automatically?

Thanks in advance

Comment: (D)DoS is always possible!

Comment: Anybody can run a DOS attack on your server, they don't need your `setInterval` to make as many requests as they want

Comment: If you have a halfway decent server, doing that will cause them a lot more problems than it will cause you. Any user can make any amount of HTTP requests to your server. That's the nature of the protocol. You *can* implement throttling, but it probably isn't worth it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting off with your "security flaw", it actually is not, it's just compromising the way the API *should* be used. Anyone can fire hundreds if not thousands of requests up to your server if their bandwidth can handle it.

This is something that would be handled on the server to prevent excess abuse, but I think it should be of a less bigger concern than you might think it is. ( Actually it should be the responsibility of your provider to protect you from these kind of attacks IMHO, but not all providers work this way unfortunately ).

For getting a more real-time kind of chat-app you might have to consider websockets / nodejs or something in that area. Otherwise you'll end up keeping regular http connections open on your (as I assume) apache server and kill it when you reach the max clients limit.

If your requirements are in a business context with hundreds of users you might want to take a good look at the libraries I advised, otherwise you could be fine with ajax requests.